# save txt data files to array function in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream

I have created a function to plot data:

```
public void ShowGraphData(long lTotalData)
{
    double[] dx = new double[lTotalData];
    double[] dy = new double[lTotalData];

    for (long li = 0; li < lTotalData; li++)
    {
         dx[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 0];
         dy[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 1];

    }
    zedGraphControlStickiness.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
    GraphPane StickinessPane = zedGraphControlStickiness.GraphPane;

    // PointPairList holds the data for plotting, X and Y arrays 
    PointPairList spl1 = new PointPairList(dx, dy);

    // Add cruves to myPane object
    LineItem ProductionCurve = StickinessPane.AddCurve("Insertion Force", spl1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
    ProductionCurve.Line.Width = 2.0F;

    zedGraphControlStickiness.AxisChange();
    zedGraphControlStickiness.Invalidate();
    zedGraphControlStickiness.Refresh();
    GlobalDataClass.iTotalReadingPoint = lTotalData;

}
```

Then i use filestream to open the txt file:

```
if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
{
     using (myStream)
     {
           //save data to list array.
     }
}
```

I need to load the txt and save the data contain several row as an array in the lToTalData in Showgraph function.
my text file is like:

---

10,20
20,30
30,40
40,50
50,60

Can some one help me how can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain better if you want to save data in a file or you want to load data from a file?

Comment: Sorry but I want to load the the data.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
List<string> _lineValues = File.ReadLines(@"File Path").ToList();
```

or

```
List<string> _lineValues = File.ReadAllLines(@"File Path").ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry but this is to create a list rite?now I want to load the data contain several rows and save it into array (lTotalData) as in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all in the conversion of the file data in the proper arrays. If you don't know the exact number of values in the input file, your best approach is to use a `List<double>` instead of a fixed length array

```
List<double> dx = new List<double>();
List<double> dy = new List<double>();

if(DialogResult.OK == openFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
{
    int x = 1;
    if(openFileDialog1.FileName != string.Empty)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        // Load everything in an IEnumerable of strings
        var lines = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        // start the enumeration
        foreach(string s in lines)
        {
            double temp;

            // If on even line put the value in the dy list
            if((x % 2) == 0)
            {
                if(double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, ci, out temp))
                    dy.Add(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                // on odd line put in the dx list
                if(double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, ci, out temp))
                    dx.Add(temp);
            }
            x++;                        
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, you have two list of doubles. Using a list instead of an array should be a better choice and it is easily replaceable (you can index the list as an array but have better functionality when you need to add new values). If you really need to use an array, you could always write

```
PointPairList spl1 = new PointPairList(dx.ToArray(), dy.ToArray());
```

However, some error checking is needed, for example what to do if one of your lines is not convertible to a double value.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand correctly, you want a double array?
then you should try something like this:

but be aware if a line in your code can't be converted to a double, this example will throw an error

```
double[] _array = File.ReadAllLines("path").Select(v => double.Parse(v)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but to make it clear, the (long lTotalData) is actually the number of rows in the text file. So the function will get the number of rows. So the code:

```
double[] dx = new double[lTotalData];
double[] dy = new double[lTotalData];

for (long li = 0; li < lTotalData; li++)
{
     dx[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 0];
     dy[li] = GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[li, 1];

}
```

It will loop the row and store each line in the array dx[li],d[li]. Consider the data in the txt is like:

x,y
x,y
x,y
x,y

now i just want to know how to pass the number of rows to the function and let the function loop the rows to get the value store in the dx,dy array.